# Neither touchesEnded nor touchesCancelled not called sometimes after touchesMoved

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, touches

I Have one circular view in my application and I am moving some objects like graph in that circular view its work fine in 90% cases but at some cases its not calling `TouchEnded` and my reset graphs code is in `TouchEnded` methods so its unloaded at some point below is my code for touches delegate methods.

```
#pragma mark - Touch Events For Rotation of GRAPH

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    prevAngle = [Utilities angleBetweenPoint:touchPoint toPoint:self.view.center];
/// convert negative angle into positive angle
    if(prevAngle < 0){
        prevAngle = PI_DOUBLE + prevAngle;
    }

    //
    [_viewStaticRadialPart hideToolTip];
}
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    CGFloat diffAngle, tempCurAngle, tempPrevAngle, curTransformAngle, newTransformAngle;

    NSLog(@"touchesMoved");
// Get the only touch (multipleTouchEnabled is NO)
    UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
    // Track the touch
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];


    curAngle = [Utilities angleBetweenPoint:touchPoint toPoint:self.view.center];

    /// convert negative angle into positive angle
    if(curAngle < 0){
        curAngle = PI_DOUBLE + curAngle;
    }
        prevAngle = curAngle;
}

-(void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self resetViewsOnceRotationStops];


}
- (void)touchesCancelled:(nullable NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(nullable UIEvent *)event
{
    [resetViewsAfterTouchStops invalidate];
    resetViewsAfterTouchStops = nil;
}
```

I am stuck here since last night so any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You tried adding a deug point in touchesEnded method?

Comment: Yes I tried to debug and its never call TouchEnded only last method call was TouchesMoved only :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know the cause for this problem from core level.

But `NSTimer` can help us in

But I feel we can resolve this by adding setting / replace `NSTimer` instance while `touchesMoved` called and we can reset that timer on `touchesEnded` and `touchesCancelled`. So, in either case, your `touchesEnded` or `touchesCancelled` not called timer will do that job and your reset logic works as it should be expected.

**Demo Source Code**

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    NSLog(@"touchesMoved");

    //Timer re-initialize code here
    if (resetViewsAfterTouchStops) {

         [resetViewsAfterTouchStops invalidate];
         resetViewsAfterTouchStops = nil;
    }

    resetViewsAfterTouchStops =  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(resetViewsOnceRotationStops) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    isTouched = NO;
    [resetViewsAfterTouchStops invalidate];
    resetViewsAfterTouchStops = nil;

    [self resetViewsOnceRotationStops];
    [self setUserInteractionOnSectorsAs:YES];
}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(nullable NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(nullable UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"touchesCancelled");
    if(resetViewsAfterTouchStops)
    {
         [self resetViewsOnceRotationStops];
         [self setUserInteractionOnSectorsAs:YES];
    }

    [resetViewsAfterTouchStops invalidate];
    resetViewsAfterTouchStops = nil;
}

- (void) resetViewsOnceRotationStops
{
    //your reset code will be place here
}
```

Comment: amorbytes, thanks for your answer but here i have one query regarding memory management that how any timer generate if i touch multiple time on my screen as my screen is using very high memory and CPU so is this solution will work without any memory issue or lagging ?

Comment: @Dhanesh : it's good question but I am reinitializing timer so, the previous timer will become `nil`, so I don't feel it will hit much on memory.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `UIGestureRecognizer` objects on that view if you are using any. `UIGestureRecognizer` objects interfere with touch events lifecycle.

Comment: Yes @Shaggy, I have tried without UIGestureRecognizer also but still didn't got any success.

Comment: Is that view embedded in a UIScrollView?

Comment: No its just plain UIView with multiple sub layers only.